# Looping a whole program in python using true and false statements

Tags: python, loops

I have written a program but I do not know how to loop it. Help would be appreciated.
Here is the program I need help with.

Comment: Post your code. Explain what it does, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: You probably want to use a [while loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop).

Comment: You have added the program as a picture. Please don't! Text in pictures can't be copied and pasted, for example. And right now the link to the picture is not even visible. So please edit your post so that it contains the code **in text format**. To format it properly, just select the whole block and press CTRL-K. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of loops: indefinite (while) loops and definite (for) loops. If you want to loop your program a specific amount of times, then use the for loop:

```
for count in range(0, <number of repetitions minus one>):
    # code
```

If you want to loop the program until the user enters "QUIT" or some other string, use this:

```
sentinel = input("Enter QUIT to exit or anything else to continue: ")
while sentinel.upper() != "QUIT":
    # code
```

Here are some helpful links to tutorials:

http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

http://www.python-course.eu/python3_for_loop.php

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/whilestatements.html#while-statements

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an infinite loop (i.e it has to go on and on without stopping) then simply use

```
white True:
    <Your code here>
```

If it's not an infinite loop and only till a certain value comes true then you can do something like:

```
counter = 0
while counter <= 10:
     print "This will continue till counter = 10"
     counter += 1
```

Answer (score -2):

You should make a function of the program, this function you can put in a loop. For further help, please post your code!